# Selenium WebDriver + TestNg - Checking the correct values have been submitted to the DB

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am using selenium webdriver + TestNG for UI tests filling out forms and submitting the values to the DB. I can check if the form was submitted if the fields were filled in etc. Once the test is complete how do you check the DB to see if the the values on the form are submitted to the DB and are the correct details?

Comment: If the submitted form inputs are meant to be visible elsewhere in your webapp (rather than, say, an email submission form) you could extend your UI tests to validate the submitted values in-context, rather than going down a level to the DB and checking the raw values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JDBC connection in your test case and run a query on your DB instance. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) that might help.